# The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__tbl8_update__HID__55F4C372"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have the following 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE
(
HID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
TABLE_NUMBER nchar(2) NOT NULL,
HOLIDAY_DATE nchar(8) NOT NULL,
FIELD_DESCRIPTION nVARchar(43) NULL,
);


CREATE TABLE tbl8_update_transactions
(
TID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
TABLE_NUMBER nchar(2) NOT NULL,
HOLIDAY_DATE nchar(8) NOT NULL,
FIELD_DESCRIPTION nVARchar(43) NULL,
HID int,
FOREIGN KEY (HID) REFERENCES HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE (HID)
);
```

When I perform a delete via my application view (Delete.cshtml), I get the following error:

"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__tbl8_update__HID__55F4C372". The conflict occurred in database "BillingUI", table "tbl8_update_transactions", column 'HID'.
The statement has been terminated."

Basically, when a delete is performed on a particular row from my view, I want it to delete the same record in both HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE and tbl8_update_transactions. I read that I have to delete the child and then the parent. I tried changing the order in which the deletes take place, however when I do this it deletes the wrong record from tbl8_update_transactions because it's looking at its primary key for identification and not its foreign key. My code is below, thanks.

```
 public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE holiday_date_table = db.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.Find(id);
        //tbl8_update_transactions tbl8_update_transaction = db.tbl8_update_transactions.Find(id);
        if (holiday_date_table == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(holiday_date_table);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Table8/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE holiday_date_table = db.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.Find(id);
        db.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.Remove(holiday_date_table);
        db.SaveChanges();
        tbl8_update_transactions tbl8_update_transaction = db.tbl8_update_transactions.Find(id);
        db.tbl8_update_transactions.Remove(tbl8_update_transaction);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("../Billing/HolidayDateTable");
    }
```

**Update:** I think I wasn't clear enough. I tried reversing them already, i.e;

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE holiday_date_table = db.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.Find(id);
        //tbl8_update_transactions tbl8_update_transaction = db.tbl8_update_transactions.Find(id);
        if (holiday_date_table == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(holiday_date_table);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Table8/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {          
        tbl8_update_transactions tbl8_update_transaction = db.tbl8_update_transactions.Find(id);
        db.tbl8_update_transactions.Remove(tbl8_update_transaction);
        db.SaveChanges();
        HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE holiday_date_table = db.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.Find(id);
        db.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.Remove(holiday_date_table);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("../Billing/HolidayDateTable");
    }
```

but it doesn't work, I receive the error "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entity", pointing to 
    db.tbl8_update_transactions.Remove(tbl8_update_transaction);

This is because (at least I think) that it's deleting from tbl8_update_transaction where it's unique identifier TID is equal to the value of HID  in HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE. I need it to delete from tbl8_update_transaction using its foreign key value and am not sure how in C#.

**Update 2:** I tried having it identify the row by the HID (foreign key) value in tbl8_update_transaction...

```
 public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0, int HID = 0)
    {
        HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE holiday_date_table = db.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.Find(id);
        tbl8_update_transactions tbl8_update_transaction = db.tbl8_update_transactions.Find(HID);
        if (holiday_date_table == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(holiday_date_table);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Table8/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id, int HID)
    {          
        tbl8_update_transactions tbl8_update_transaction = db.tbl8_update_transactions.Find(HID);
        db.tbl8_update_transactions.Remove(tbl8_update_transaction);
        db.SaveChanges();
        HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE holiday_date_table = db.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.Find(id);
        db.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.Remove(holiday_date_table);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("../Billing/HolidayDateTable");
    }
```

But get the following error:
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'HID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(Int32, Int32)' in 'BillingApp.Controllers.Table8Controller'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the child table's `Foreign Key` Constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl8_update_transactions
(
TID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
TABLE_NUMBER nchar(2) NOT NULL,
HOLIDAY_DATE nchar(8) NOT NULL,
FIELD_DESCRIPTION nVARchar(43) NULL,
HID int,
FOREIGN KEY (HID) REFERENCES HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE (HID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The `ON DELETE CASCADE` implements a cascading delete on the parent table's rows which will delete the associated child table's rows when a parent table's row is deleted.

Comment: you might look closely at your explanation. The CASCADE DELETE will not automatically delete the parent when the child is deleted. It is the other way around. When the parent is deleted, it will cascade the delete and remove ALL the children.

Answer (score 4):

You need to flip your Remove methods around. You are deleting the parent first when there is still a child. You need to first delete the row from tbl8_update_transaction and then holiday_date_table.

```
tbl8_update_transactions tbl8_update_transaction = db.tbl8_update_transactions.Find(id);
db.tbl8_update_transactions.Remove(tbl8_update_transaction);
db.SaveChanges();
HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE holiday_date_table = db.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.Find(id);
db.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.Remove(holiday_date_table);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: this keeps getting upvoted yet is not a solution to my problem lol

Answer (score 1):

You should delete all the objects where this ID is Foreign key. They will be not valid if you delete this reference, because of that you have this exception.